# How can the pop up load seconds after the page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

So I have been trying this for hours since I have no huge experience in JavaScript. Basically, I have modified a CSS and HTML codes for the pop up, that I found on the web. However, I would love to make the pop up to show up 10 seconds after a page load. I have tried lots of methods, but none of them gave me the result I wanted. Actually, none of them worked, even partially. 
Here is the latest method, which also didn't work.

```js
function toggle(div_id) {
 var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
 if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
 else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}
function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
  viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
 } else {
  viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 }
 if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
  blanket_height = viewportheight;
 } else {
  if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
   blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
  } else {
   blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
  }
 }
 var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
 blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
 var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
 popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-200;//200 is half popup's height
 popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}
function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
  viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
 } else {
  viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 }
 if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
  window_width = viewportwidth;
 } else {
  if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
   window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
  } else {
   window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
  }
 }
 var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
 window_width=window_width/2-200;//200 is half popup's width
 popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}
function popup(windowname) {
 blanket_size(windowname);
 window_pos(windowname);
 toggle('blanket');
 toggle(windowname);  
}
window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 27 ) {
        console.log( 'ESC' );
  document.getElementById('popUpDiv').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
 font-family:Palatino, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;
 background:#190121;
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center; 
 color: #000000;
}
 #container {
 width: 780px;  
 background: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 font-size:14px;
 
 text-align: left; 
}
#mainContent {
 padding: 0 60px;
 min-height:600px;
 line-height:25px
}

img {border:0px}




/*LINKS*/

#mainContent .gamortva:link {
color:#ffffff; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:8px; 
background:#000000; 
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
}
#mainContent .gamortva:visited {
color:#ffffff; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:8px; 
background:#000000; 
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
}
#mainContent .gamortva:hover {
color:#ffffff; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:9px; 
background:#333333; 
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px
}
#mainContent .gamortva:active {
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:9px; 
background:#333333; 
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px
}



/*STYLES FOR CSS POPUP*/


#blanket {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   *background:none;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 9001;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
   -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

#popUpDiv {
 position:absolute;
 background:url(***.jpg) no-repeat;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 border:5px solid #000;
 z-index: 9002;
}



.amazonis-knopka:link {
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 30px;
color:white;
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:40px; 
background:#000000; 
opacity:0.8; 
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius:20px;
}

.amazonis-knopka:hover{
padding: 10px;
text-decoration:underline; 
font-size:43px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
opacity:1;
}

.amazonis-knopka:visited{
color:white;
}

#mainContent .gamortva:active {
color:#ffffff;
}

.popTitle {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 background:#333333; 
 padding:19px; 
 -webkit-border-radius:100px;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 display: block;
 color:white;
 font-size:23px; 
}

.popText {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 padding:30px; 
 -webkit-border-radius:20px;
 -moz-border-radius:20px;
 background: rgba(144, 154, 56, 0.3);
 font-size:25px; 
 font-weight: bolder;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Pop Up</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPopUp() {
  element = document.getElementById("popUpDiv");
 }
window.onload = setTimeout(openPopUp, 10000);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css-pop.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="popup('popUpDiv')">
<div id="container">


  <div id="mainContent">
  
  
  
  
<p><strong>Pop Up</strong> Beta <em>V1</em></p>

    
    <div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
 <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
     <a href="#" class="gamortva" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" >Close</a>
  <span class="popTitle">Heading!..</span>
  
  <span class="popText">Text..</span>

    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="amazonis-knopka">Link...</a>
 </div>
  <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click Here To Open The Pop Up</a>
    
    

    
    
    
    
  </div>
 </div>



</body>
</html>
```

The setTimeout code is the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function openPopUp() {
  element = document.getElementById("popUpDiv");
 }
window.onload = setTimeout(openPopUp, 10000);
</script>
```

I thought maybe if I could load the pop up with the `<script>` code it would be very helpful, because I don't really like that the pop up is being loaded with the body tag: `<body onload="popup('popUpDiv')">`
But, I could not manage to do that, because the pop up does not load after I try to load it with the function. Maybe I was doing it wrong, but I have tried everything I could think of, and almost everything I found on web.

**I know I have a lot of other mistakes other than the pop up, I am still working on them.**

Sorry for not being very specific and copying entire codes, but without those I thought it would be hard to figure out what I was trying to do.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run your function in right place )

```js
function toggle(div_id) {
 var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
 if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
 else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}
function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
  viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
 } else {
  viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 }
 if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
  blanket_height = viewportheight;
 } else {
  if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
   blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
  } else {
   blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
  }
 }
 var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
 blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
 var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
 popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-200;//200 is half popup's height
 popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}
function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
  viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
 } else {
  viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 }
 if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
  window_width = viewportwidth;
 } else {
  if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
   window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
  } else {
   window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
  }
 }
 var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
 window_width=window_width/2-200;//200 is half popup's width
 popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}
function popup(windowname) {
    blanket_size(windowname);
    window_pos(windowname);
    toggle('blanket');
    toggle(windowname);  
}
window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 27 ) {
        console.log( 'ESC' );
  document.getElementById('popUpDiv').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function openPopUp() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    popup('popUpDiv');
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
 font-family:Palatino, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;
 background:#190121;
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center; 
 color: #000000;
}
 #container {
 width: 780px;  
 background: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 font-size:14px;
 
 text-align: left; 
}
#mainContent {
 padding: 0 60px;
 min-height:600px;
 line-height:25px
}

img {border:0px}




/*LINKS*/

#mainContent .gamortva:link {
color:#ffffff; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:8px; 
background:#000000; 
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
}
#mainContent .gamortva:visited {
color:#ffffff; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:8px; 
background:#000000; 
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
}
#mainContent .gamortva:hover {
color:#ffffff; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:9px; 
background:#333333; 
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px
}
#mainContent .gamortva:active {
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:9px; 
background:#333333; 
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px
}



/*STYLES FOR CSS POPUP*/


#blanket {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   *background:none;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 9001;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
   -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

#popUpDiv {
 position:absolute;
 background:url(iRobot.jpg) no-repeat;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 border:5px solid #000;
 z-index: 9002;
}



.amazonis-knopka:link {
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 30px;
color:white;
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:40px; 
background:#000000; 
opacity:0.8; 
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius:20px;
}

.amazonis-knopka:hover{
padding: 10px;
text-decoration:underline; 
font-size:43px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
opacity:1;
}

.amazonis-knopka:visited{
color:white;
}

#mainContent .gamortva:active {
color:#ffffff;
}

.popTitle {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 background:#333333; 
 padding:19px; 
 -webkit-border-radius:100px;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 display: block;
 color:white;
 font-size:23px; 
}

.popText {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 padding:30px; 
 -webkit-border-radius:20px;
 -moz-border-radius:20px;
 background: rgba(144, 154, 56, 0.3);
 font-size:25px; 
 font-weight: bolder;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Pop Up</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="css-pop.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="openPopUp()">
<div id="container">


  <div id="mainContent">
  
  
  
  
<p>Roomba iRobot <strong>Pop Up</strong> Beta <em>V1</em></p>

    
    <div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
 <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
     <a href="#" class="gamortva" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" >Close</a>
  <span class="popTitle">Heading!..</span>
  
  <span class="popText">Text..</span>

    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="amazonis-knopka">Link...</a>
 </div>
  <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click Here To Open The Pop Up</a>
    
    

    
    
    
    
  </div>
 </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That exactly works the way I wanted it to do! Thank you for such a simple, yet functional answer.

Comment: So you think the <body onload="openPopUp()"> is not the bad way to do it right? I mean to run the pop up function from the body tag.

Comment: Why not? If you don't want to use jQuery and it's `$( document ).ready()` you could use this solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help, solved all my problems.